# Cannot cast org.bson.BsonRegularExpression to java.lang.String

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, bson

I'm learning to make microservices using Spring framework but I ran into a problem.

I'm using mongodb as a database and i'm trying to create a kind of "online library" where my client would be able to retrieves JSON's using my RestController.

My book entity looks like such :

```
public class Books {
    @MongoId(value = FieldType.OBJECT_ID)
    private String id;
    private String author;
    private String publisher;
    private String title;
    private String isbn;
    private int    stock;

    // more code useless for the example
    // field name is "authors" in my db as I found an external JSON online for testing my functionnalities while my data uses "author" instead as a name.
    @JsonProperty("authors")
    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public void setAuthor(String author) {
        this.author = author;
    }
```

As you can see nothing fancy here, I wanna use this getter in other to find books that matchs by author name.

here is the code of how I accomplish this :

```
@Repository
public interface BookRepository extends MongoRepository<Books, String> {
   //@Query("{ authors: { $in: [ /.*?0.*/ ] } }")  this query works aswell if I use it mongo COMPASS
   @Query("{ authors: /.*?0.*/ } ")
   public List<Books> findByAuthor(String authors);

   // Other queries
}
```

which will be passed throught a service :

```
@Service
public class BookService {
    @Autowired
    private BookRepository repository;

    public List<Books> findByAuthor(String author) {
        return repository.findByAuthor(author);
    }

    // other methods useless for the example
}
```

and finally the Controller :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "library/")
public class BookController {
    @Autowired
    private BookService bookService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "book/author/{author}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<Books> getBookByAuthor(@PathVariable(value = "author") String author) {
        return bookService.findByAuthor(author);
    }

    // Other useless stuff removed for clarity

}
```

Now if i'm about to have access to my link (localhost:8082/library/book/author/And) ("And" is standing only because I wanna find authors that contains "And in their name) i'm getting the following error in POSTMAN :

```
{
    "timestamp": "2020-05-15T23:36:06.198+0000",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "Cannot cast org.bson.BsonRegularExpression to java.lang.String",
    "path": "/library/book/author/And"
}
```

I've tried to figure out the issue on my own, but couldn't find any situation that apply's to my problem online. Note that i'm absolutely not familiar of how BSON's work. I just have a rough idea of why it is used when I visit the official web page.

Until now all my other methods and query that i've created worked perfectly until now and I felt a bit loss as i'm new in the domain :)

Thank you for any upcoming help !

Comment: did you try `bookService.findByAuthor(author)` converting this result  to json

Comment: i'm confused, on all my other queries everything was converted into Json by default. If I remembered correctly this was due because of the @RestController annotation available in my Controller. Could you explain me why this time i need to convert manually ?

Comment: is there any other queries returning list of objects? if  exist can you check they working or not?

Comment: yes there is, using the following query :
    @Query("{stock: {$gt: 0}}")
    public List<Books> hasInStock();
and it's working perfectly. Also I tried to add this as you requested above : 
@RequestMapping(value = "book/author/{author}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE) still not working :/

Comment: Wrapping string in quotes may occurs problems.Try without @Query like `List<Books> findByFirstnameContaining(String authors);`

Comment: Hello ! It worked. i'm so confused of the why it didn't work previously. Thank you for the work arround ! since the answer was posted as a comment, am I supposed to close the post ? :)